# Angular e2e test Chromedriver: Failed: element click intercepted: Element is not clickable at point (512, 828)

Tags: angular, protractor

I use Protractor for Angular e2e tests.

I have a test doing a traetment with a SnackBar used for confirmation.

The test does 2 aserts like that:

```
expect(myPage.hasConfirmMessage('Test message OK')).toBe(true);
expect(myPage.getTestedField()).toBe('OK');
```

The problem I have is that the second assert sometimes fails because, I think, the SnackBar is not closed yet. It closes automatically after few seconds. The failure is that the value of TestedField is considered as empty but it is not (it is 'OK' as expected).

I tried to solve it by using this between the two asserts:

```
myPage.closeConfirmMessage();
```

It does a click to close it.

But I have the following error:

```
Failed: element click intercepted: Element is not clickable at point (512, 828)
```

I think it is because the confirmation message is already closed when the closeConfirmMessage() function is called no?

As the element is not static but displayed only for few seconds, I do not know how to close it only if necessary before doing the other assert.

Can you help me with this error please?

Answer (score 0):

This test is written partially in webdriver but with a mix of Protractor APIs. You'll need to wait for the snackbar to disappear. After your snackbar disappears you could check if the snackbar message is stale.

```
  it('should wait for the presence and staleness of the snackbar message', async () => {
    let snackButton = await driver.findElement(WebDriverBy.id('snackbar'));
    await snackButton.click();
    let condition = false;
    await driver.wait(async () => {
      condition = await ec.presenceOf(
          element(by.css('.snackbar-message')))();
      return condition;
    }, 5000);
    expect(condition).toBeTruthy();

    // wait 3 seconds for the snackbar message to disappear.
    await new Promise(resolve => {
      setTimeout(resolve, 3000);
    });

    await driver.wait(async () => {
      condition = await ec.stalenessOf(
          element(by.css('.snackbar-message')))();
      return condition;
    }, 5000);
    expect(condition).toBeTruthy();
  });
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. If I understand well your solution, you wait for the presence of the snackbar in the dom, then you wait 3 seconds and then you wait for the snackbar to be no more in the DOM (stalenessOf). Is it right? Why do you wait 3 seconds if you wait for sncackbar to be no more in DOM (stalenessOf) after that please?

Comment: I was reimplementing the expected conditions API and did not have stalenessOf done so I slept the browser for 3 seconds. This is not needed and I should probably fix my test in my repo.